# Why cant I pass a chart to my subroutine

Tags: vba, excel

I have a SubRoutine with the following signature:

```
Sub SetChartGraphScale(theChart As Chart, theMin, theMax)
```

In another SubRoutine, I can call SetChartGraphScale and it behaves as expected:

```
Set theChartObject = .ChartObjects.Add( _
        Left:=0, Top:=50, Width:=.100, Height:=50)
SetChartGraphScale theChartObject.Chart, 0, 30
```

But when I try to call it from a different SubRoutine:

```
Set theChart = Charts.Add
SetChartGraphScale theChart, 0, 30
```

I get this error:

[image]

But if I call using ActiveChart, everything works fine:

```
Set theChart = Charts.Add
SetChartGraphScale ActiveChart, 0, 30
```

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196568(v=office.14).aspx, Charts.Add returns a Chart, so I don't understand why I can't pass it through to SetChartGraphScale.  I can send the ActiveChart as a workaround, but I really want to understand why this isn't behaving as I think it should.

I am trying to avoid ActiveSheet, ActiveChart, etc as much as possible to protect against screwing things up if the user is clicking around while the macro is running.

Comment: You need `Dim theChart as Chart` in your calling routine.

Comment: You could pass it as a reference `ByRef theChart as Chart` or as a value `ByVal theChart as Chart`. Given Chart is object type, by reference is preferred.

Comment: Also **don't forget to provide the correct data type for the other two variables** in your sub. *e.g. the Min, the Max*